# index.js has no imports and no systemjs config is created

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I just created a new Angular project with `ng new some-name`, but the created `index.html` contains no `<script>` tags and no SystemJS configuration is created.
Is this the correct behavior? I would expect the CLI to create a simple running project.

Comment: Angular CLI doesn't use SystemJS any more, it moved to Webpack. Which version of it are you using? Can you actually e.g. `ng serve` the project, and if not what errors do you get when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is expected behavior. Webpack is used internally in the cli, which by itself injects all the needed script and style tags dynamically when serving/building.

Run `ng serve` and see that it should serve successfully (locahost:4200).

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear, but you are right and it's working thanks!

Comment: Running `ng build -prod` will create the production build in `/dist`. There you should see the `<script>` references.